# C# ef second operation started before previous asynchronous operation completed

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await

Just trying to do normal query on ef but getting below error message

"A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed"

I am using await for all aync call but not sure what could be causing this issue.

here' code

```
    var sids = await context.Sites.Where(s => slist.Contains(s.JVSiteID)).ToListAsync();

    var header = await context.GenericCsvHeaders.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Header == csvh) ?? new GenericCsvHeader { Header = csvh };

    context.Entry<GenericCsvHeader>(header).State = (header.GenericCsvHeaderID == 0) ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Unchanged;

    var sa = await context.SAs.Where(x => x.StatusID == Data.Enum.Status.Active && mapkeys.Contains(x.SAName)).Select(x => new { x.SAName, x.SACode, x.SAID }).ToListAsync();

    if (sa.Count > 0)
        sasitelist = await context.Site_SA.Where(x => x.StatusID == Data.Enum.Status.Active && siteids.Contains(x.SiteID ?? 0)).ToListAsync();

    var az = await context.Azimuths.Where(x => x.StatusID == Data.Enum.Status.Active && mapkeys.Contains(x.AzimuthName)).Select(x => new { x.AzimuthName, x.AzimuthID }).ToListAsync();

    if (az.Count > 0)
           azsitelist = await context.Site_Azimuth.Where(x => x.StatusID == Data.Enum.Status.Active && siteids.Contains(x.SiteID ?? 0)).ToListAsync();

    var rows = new List<dynamic>(); //getting this list from csv file via csvHelper

     foreach (var r in rows)
       {
           var s = sids.FirstOrDefault(x => x.JVSiteID == (((IDictionary<String, Object>)r)[siteid]).ToString()) ?? new Site();
            UpdateSite(s, r, map);
       }


    private async void UpdateSite(Site site, dynamic csvSite, IDictionary<string, string> map)
    {

       context.Entry(site).State = (site.StateID == 0) ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
       site.SiteForAuditTrail = site;
       if (map.ContainsKey("SiteName") && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(GetStringOfDynamic(map,csvSite,"SiteName")))
             site.SiteName = GetStringOfDynamic(map,csvSite, "SiteName");

       if (map.ContainsKey("State") && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(GetStringOfDynamic(map,csvSite, "State")))
         {
            //getting exception at below line
             var state = (await GetRefTypeList<State>(x => x.StateCode == GetStringOfDynamic(map,csvSite, "State"))) ?? new State { StateCode = GetStringOfDynamic(map,csvSite, "State") };

          context.Entry(state).State = (state.StateID == 0) ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Unchanged;
           site.State = state;
          state.SiteForAuditTrail = site;
     }

  }


private async Task<T> GetRefTypeList<T>(Func<T, bool> expression) where T : EntityBase
 {
       if (!refTypes.ContainsKey(typeof(T).Name))
              refTypes[typeof(T).Name] = (await context.Set<T>().Where(x => x.StatusID == Data.Enum.Status.Active).ToListAsync());

       return (refTypes[typeof(T).Name] as List<T>)?.FirstOrDefault(expression);
 }


private string GetStringOfDynamic(IDictionary<string, string> map,dynamic obj, string propertyName)
 {
    if (((IDictionary<String, Object>)obj).ContainsKey(map[propertyName]))
          return (((IDictionary<String, Object>)obj)[map[propertyName]]??"").ToString();

         return "";
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found problem, was missing await when calling UpdateSite

```
 foreach (var r in rows)
       {
           var s = sids.FirstOrDefault(x => x.JVSiteID == (((IDictionary<String, Object>)r)[siteid]).ToString()) ?? new Site();
          **await**  UpdateSite(s, r, map);
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having a race condition here. While you are using await you have other code executing potentially before the variable sids, header, sa and az, have been returned.

You should refactor your code so that the remaining code is not executed until these variables are returned. You can do this by using a task and then using the extension `WhenAll` which will ensure each await has been completed before proceeding. [Here is a link to MS docs on Task and WhenAll implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/how-to-extend-the-async-walkthrough-by-using-task-whenall)

Comment: "While you are using await you have other code executing potentially before the variable sids, header, sa and az, have been returned"

not quite clear of this. sids is where the method starts before that I am reading csv file with csvHelper and using ef. Can you please explain above statement bit more. Thanks

Comment: think what Task and WhenAll are used for is different, its when you want to do something like

list<Task<result>> tasks ;
tasks.add(GetAsync(1));
tasks.add(getAsync(2));
await Task.whenAll(tasks);